# How to execute a javascript function immediately after D3 has rendered a graph

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I  am working on a dynamic page, that shows a scatter plot given some parameters. I would like to call the  function download_SVG immediately after the diagram is rendered. The problem is that I am getting the data from a server, so the function, which saves the diagram as a SVG file, is always called before the scatter plot is done loading, leading to an empty SVG file. I have tried with setTimeOut() with no success.

Is there any good solution for this problem?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    //Get list of dataset.
    $("#dataset").load('/mysite/php/getDataset.php', function(){
        var getSVG;
        var urldata = window.location.href;
        //console.log(window.location.href);
        var data = getParams(urldata);

        if(data != null){
            var gene = data["gene"];
            var dataset = data["dataset"];
            var exportSvg = data["exportsvg"];
            getSVG = data["SVG"];
            var e = document.getElementById("probeSelect");
            var probe = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
            settingSVG(getSVG);

            
            loadGraph(gene, dataset, probe);
            getAbbList(dataset);
            changeSelectedDataset(dataset);

            
            //setTimeout(download_SVG("mainSVG", "scatter"),6000);
            //console.log(data["gene"]);
            //console.log(data["dataset"]);   
        }
    });
});

function drawCircles() {
    //console.log(datasetChanged);
    //This selects 4 circles (non-existent, there requires data-binding) and appends them all below  enter.
    //The amount of numbers in data is the amount of circles to be appended in the enter() section.

    if(datasetChanged){
        SVG.selectAll("circle").remove();
    }
    if(SVG.selectAll("circle").empty() ){
        animationNum = 0;
        animationNumMedian = 0;
    } else if(selectPopulation){
        animationNum = 1;
        animationNumMedian = 2;
    } else if(probeChanged || log2Data){
        animationNum = 2;
        animationNumMedian = 1;
    } else {
        animationNum = 3;
        animationNumMedian = 0;
        //animationNum = randomIntFromInterval(1, 4);
    }
        
    var circle = SVGbody
        .selectAll("circle")
        .data(graphDataY);

    circle.exit()
        .style("opacity", CIRCLE_OPACITY)
        .transition()
        .duration(ANIMATION_TIME_MODIFIER*300)
        .style("opacity", 0)
        .remove();

    circle.enter()
        .append("circle")
        .on("mouseover", function(d) {      
            div.transition()        
                .duration(100)      
                .style("opacity", .9);
            div.html(d)  
                .style("left", (d3.event.pageX) + "px")     
                .style("top", (d3.event.pageY - 28) + "px");    
            })                  
        .on("mouseout", function(d) {       
            div.transition()        
                .duration(300)      
                .style("opacity", 0);   
        });

    var amountOfCircles = d3.selectAll("circle").size();
    
    var iOS = ( navigator.userAgent.match(/(iPad|iPhone|iPod)/g) ? true : false );
    if(d3.selectAll("circle").size() > 3000 || iOS){
        animationNum = 9;
    }

    switch(animationNum){
        case 0:
        //Executed on init and when dataset is changed.
        circle
            .attr("cx",xScale(0))
            .attr("cy", yScale(minAxisY))
            .attr("r",4)
            .style('opacity', 0)
            .style("fill", function(d, i){ return graphDataColors[i]; })
            .transition()
            .duration(ANIMATION_TIME_MODIFIER*1000)
            .attr("cx", function(d, i){ return xScale(graphDataX[i]);})
            //.attr("cy", function (d, i){ return yScale(i); })
            .style('opacity', CIRCLE_OPACITY)
            .transition()
            .duration(ANIMATION_TIME_MODIFIER*1000)
            .attr("cy", function(d){return yScale(parseFloat(d));} );
        break;
        case 1:
        //Executed when select population is changed. Remove all dots below the graph and pulls the new data back up.
        circle
            .attr("cx", function(d, i){ return xScale(graphDataX[i]);})
            .attr("cy", function(d){return yScale(parseFloat(d));} )
            .attr("r",4)
            .style('opacity', 0)
            .style("fill",  function(d, i){ return graphDataColors[i]; })
            .transition().duration(ANIMATION_TIME_MODIFIER*500)
            .style('opacity', CIRCLE_OPACITY);
        break;
        case 2:
        //Executed when probe is changed. Changes the position og circles to quickly update the graph.
        circle
            .transition()
            .duration(ANIMATION_TIME_MODIFIER*1000)
            .attr("cx", function(d, i){ return xScale(graphDataX[i]);})
            .attr("cy", function(d){return yScale(parseFloat(d));} )
            .attr("r",4)
            .style('opacity', CIRCLE_OPACITY)
            .style("fill",  function(d, i){ return graphDataColors[i]; });
        break;
        case 3:
        //Executed when gene is changed. Gathers all circles in the middles, spreads the out at the bottom, and lastly pulls them to their places.
        circle
            .transition().duration(ANIMATION_TIME_MODIFIER*750)
            .style("fill", function(d, i){ return graphDataColors[i]; })
            .attr("r",4)
            .style('opacity', CIRCLE_OPACITY)
            .attr("cx", width/2)
            .attr("cy", height/2)
            .transition()
            .attr("cx", function(d, i){ return xScale(graphDataX[i]);})
            .attr("cy", yScale(minAxisY))
            .transition()
            .attr("cy",function(d){return yScale(parseFloat(d));});
        break;
        case 9:
        circle
            .attr("cx", function(d, i){ return xScale(graphDataX[i]);})
            .attr("cy", function(d){return yScale(parseFloat(d));} )
            .attr("r",4)
            .style('opacity', 0)
            .style("fill",  function(d, i){ return graphDataColors[i]; })
            .transition().duration(ANIMATION_TIME_MODIFIER*1000)
            .style('opacity', CIRCLE_OPACITY);
        break;
        case 10:
        circle
            .attr("cx", function(d, i){ return xScale(graphDataX[i]);})
            .attr("cy", function(d){return yScale(parseFloat(d));} )
            .attr("r",4)
            .style("fill",  function(d, i){ return graphDataColors[i]; })
            .style('opacity', CIRCLE_OPACITY);
        break;
    }

    //console.log(d3.selectAll("circle").size());

    //CSS for circles
    $("circle").css({"stroke":"#404040","stroke-width":"1px"});
}


function processDatalol(gene, dataset, probe, data){
initValues();
        //If a new gene or dataset is chosen, no probes have been chosen by default. If new probe has been chosen, we ignore this.
        //console.log("Current gene: " + currentGene + ", New gene: " + gene);
if(currentGene != gene || datasetChanged){
            chosenProbe = "none";
            gene = makeUpperCase(gene, dataset);
            currentGene = gene;
            graphDataProbes = Array();
            SVG.selectAll(".graphTitle")
                .transition().duration(ANIMATION_TIME_MODIFIER*800)
                .attr("x", width/2)
                .attr("y", 0)
                .style("text-anchor", "middle")
                .style("font-size", "16")
                .style("font-family", "helvetica")
                .style("font-weight", "bold")
                .transition().duration(ANIMATION_TIME_MODIFIER*700)
                .attr("x", width/2)
                .attr("y", 90)
                .text(currentGene);

            SVG.selectAll(".title")
                .transition().duration(ANIMATION_TIME_MODIFIER*1500)
                .style("font-size", "500")
                .style("opacity", "0")
                .remove();
        }

        if(typeof data !== 'undefined' && data.length > 0) {

            //console.log(data);

            changeAxisLabel(dataset);

            data.forEach( function(d) {
                arrayValues.push(d.cell_name);
                var cell_data = JSON.stringify(d.cell_data);
                var probe_name = JSON.stringify(d.probe_name);
                console.log(d);
                //console.log(probe_name);
                cell_data = cell_data.replace(/"/g,"");
                probe_name = probe_name.replace(/"/g,"");
                if(chosenProbe == "none"){
                    chosenProbe = probe_name;
                }
                if(probeChanged == true){
                    chosenProbe = probe;
                }
                
                if((chosenProbe == probe_name) || (probe == MAX_PROBE)){
                        graphDataSubValueY.push(cell_data.split(" "));
                }
                graphDataProbes.push(probe_name);
                graphDataFullArray.push(cell_data.split(" "));
            });

            //console.log(graphDataFullArray);
            console.log(graphDataSubValueY);


            if(!$("#Log2_scale").is(':checked')){
                graphDataSubValueY = convert2DArrayToLog2(graphDataSubValueY);
            }

            arrayValues = removeDuplicatesInArray(arrayValues);
            graphDataProbes = removeDuplicatesInArray(graphDataProbes);

            //console.log(arrayValues);
            //console.log(graphDataProbes);

            chooseSearchedProbe();

            calculateMedian();

            updateTreeGraph(dataset);

            //Open survival plot for probe
            $(".survPlot").attr("src","/mysite/surv/survplotsPNG/" + chosenProbe + ".png");
            $(".survPlot").error(function () { 
                $(".survPlot").attr("src","/mysite/surv/survplotsPNG/No_Survival_Data.png");
            });

            updateCheckboxes();

            findBiggestCelltype(probe);
            calculateMinMaxValues();
            calculateCoordinatesXY();
            updateAllAxis();

            // Change probes and ttest lists avaliable to user.
            refreshProbeSelect(graphDataProbes);
            refreshTTestList(arrayValues);
            changeSelectedProbe(chosenProbe, gene);

            //Draw circles and possibly medians.
            drawCircles();
            if($("#median").is(':checked')){
                drawMedians();
            }

            //Get correlations from database and create buttons that will link to them.
            getCorrelations(dataset, chosenProbe);

            //Update global booleans after process is done.
            setProbeChanged(false);
            setDatasetChanged(false);
            setSelectPopulation(false);
            setLog2Data(false);
            animationNum = 1;

            //Take a backup of maxAxisY.
            maxAxisY_backup = maxAxisY;
        }
```

}

Comment: assuming that `loadGraph` is your D3 function, try having it return to a callback when it completes loading the graph.

Comment: I am not sure, how to do that? .each("end", mycallback); ??

Comment: You should post more of your code, including the D3 code

Comment: I have added the drawcircles function, which makes the dots in the scatter plot

Comment: I'm never seeing `drawCirlces` get called.

Comment: Usually the best idea in these situations is to strip everything unrelated to the problem and put the code into [JSBin](http://jsbin.com) and see if the problem still persists. This makes it significantly easier to debug, and to allow others to debug.

Comment: I have added some ekstra code.